# Using a guard to check the value of a textfield

Tags: ios, swift3, guard

I'm trying to use a guard instead of a if/else statement to check to see if my input field is empty or had the default text in it. This is the guard I'm trying to use, but it always fails, even if the textfield has something in it other then the default text.

```
guard (name.text?.isEmpty)!, name.text! == "Add Name" else{
        // call the warning function
        warningMessage()
        return
    }
    print("made it")
    // dismiss the viewcontroller
```

This is what I would use for an if/else statement

```
     if(personName.text == "" || personName.text == "Add a name"){
         warningMessage()
      }else{
             }
```

Comment: It's failing because `name.text!` isn't `Add Name`.

Comment: The default text is Add Name. But even when I add something else like "John" it still fails.

Comment: Your logic is backwards. You want to pass through if `!(name.text?.isEmpty!), name.text! != "Add Name"`

Comment: I updated the question to show you the if else statement.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextfield/1619621-placeholder

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is wrong, and the way you've written it, it will crash if name.text is nil.

You want something like this:

```
placeholder = name.placeholder ?? ""
guard let text = name.text,
  !text.isEmpty {
    // call the warning function
    warningMessage()
    return
}
print("made it")
```

That says:

> Exit if name.text is nil, if it is empty, or if it contains
> the placeholder value

### EDIT:

As pointed out by @LeoDabus in comments, you should use the placeholder string on your text field rather than setting the text value. Then you don't need to compare against a starting text value.

Comment: I don't think `name.text` will in fact ever be `nil`, will it? I've never seen that actually happen.

Comment: Dunno. It is declared as an optional for some reason, and the comments in the framework header say "default is nil". I avoid force-unwrapping unless I'm abso-freaking-lutely certain it can never be nil. Plus, a `guard let` simplifies the syntax of the code that follows.

Comment: @DuncanC you misunderstood my comment Just assign "Add name" to the texfield placeholder instead of setting it as the textfield text and remove that condition from the guard. The text property won't be equal to its placeholder property. When the user begin editing it disappears

Answer (score 0):

```
guard let text = name.text, text.isEmpty || text == "Add Name" else {
    if name.text == nil { 
        // input field is empty     
    }
    return
}

// input field is empty or had the default text in it
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be sure that

- the textfield is **not** empty
- AND does warningMessage() contain the String `"Add Name"`

you can write

```
guard name.text?.isEmpty == false, name.text != "Add Name" else {
    warningMessage()
    return
}
print("made it")
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting "Add Name" in the `text` property, why not put it in `placeholder` property? That way, you only have check if it is empty. You can change the color of the placeholder text to look like it's normal.

```
guard let text = name.text, text.isEmpty 
    else { return }
```